# Ruta personalizada en Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4, routes

Estoy configurando unas rutas en codeingiter 4, necesito que al solicitar por el método GET la dirección catalogos y cualquier palabra me envíe al controlador Catalogos pero si agrega catalogos/auto me envíe al controlador Catalogos/completeData, por ejemplo

```
catalogos/datos => Catalogos
catalogos/1     => Catalogos
catalogos/auto  => Catalogos/completeData
```

El archivo route.php lo tengo así

```
$routes->get('catalogos/(:any)', 'Catalogos/$1');
$routes->get('catalogos/auto/(:any)', 'Catalogos/completeData/$2');
```

La petición para cualquier palabra es:

```
catalogos/ps
```

*Esta función bien y manda al método index del controlador Catalogos*

La petición que realizo para auto es:

```
catalogos/auto?term=01
```

Esta también envía al index **pero quiero que envíe al método completeData más el parámetro term**

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado a cambiar el orden de las rutas? Así te aseguras de que 'catalogos/auto' vaya a 'Catalogos/completeData'. Creo que tal como está ahora el 'auto' acaba como (:any) de la primera ruta pues cumple el criterio y CI no pasa de ahí.

Comment: Ya la había corregido y si fue agregando la ruta de `catalogos/auto` primero